# Understanding how bit-shifting works with Negative Shift Values in Java

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, operators, bit, bit-shift

I am writing a simple program to determine unique characters in a string. I can do this an easier, less efficient way using an Array, but I am trying to implement it using a bit vector. I am able to get correct output fine but I am unsure about why I get the correct output.

My code:

```
class Main {  
  public static void main(String args[]) { 
    System.out.println(isUniqueChars("Robert")); 
  }
  
  public static boolean isUniqueChars(String str) {
      int checker = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
          int val = str.charAt(i) - 'a';
          System.out.println("Val: " + val); //Val = -15 First Iteration
          System.out.print("1 << val: "); //Equals 131072
          System.out.println(1 << val);
          if ((checker & (1 << val)) > 0) {
              return false;
          }
          System.out.print("Checker: ");
          checker = checker | (1 << val);
          System.out.println(checker); //Equals 131072
          System.out.println();
      }
      return true;
  }
}
```

I am trying to figure out why 1 << -15 yields 131072. I have searched the internet and have watched a couple of tutorials on shift operators but none of them explain negative shift values.

Answer (score 2):

From the JLS:

> If the promoted type of the left-hand operand is int, then only the five lowest-order bits of the right-hand operand are used as the shift distance. It is as if the right-hand operand were subjected to a bitwise logical AND operator & (§15.22.1) with the mask value 0x1f (0b11111). The shift distance actually used is therefore always in the range 0 to 31, inclusive.
>
> If the promoted type of the left-hand operand is long, then only the six lowest-order bits of the right-hand operand are used as the shift distance. It is as if the right-hand operand were subjected to a bitwise logical AND operator & (§15.22.1) with the mask value 0x3f (0b111111). The shift distance actually used is therefore always in the range 0 to 63, inclusive.

The constant `1` is an `int`, so the `-15`, which is `0xfffffff1` is masked to `0x00000011` indicating a left shift of 17 bits, which is exactly `131072`.

Answer (score 1):

One way of looking at it is the bits are shifted in a positive `modulo 32` fashion.  So what positive number between `0 and 32` is congruent to `-15 mod 32`?  By adding `32` to `-15` you get `17`.  So it's the same as shifting by `17`.  In fact shifting `-15 + k*32` where `k` is an integer will shift the same amount of bits as shown below.

```
int k = 4;
int v = 1; 
for (int i = -15+(32*-k); i < -15+(32*k); i+= 32) {
  int res = v << i;
  System.out.printf("1 << %4d == %d%n", i, res );
}
```

prints

```
1 << -143 == 131072
1 << -111 == 131072
1 <<  -79 == 131072
1 <<  -47 == 131072
1 <<  -15 == 131072
1 <<   17 == 131072
1 <<   49 == 131072
1 <<   81 == 131072
```

This also means you can't clear an int by `<< 32`.  You need to left shift `31` and then left shift `1`. Or more generally, left shift by `k` and then left shift by `32-k` where `1 <= k < 32`.

```
int k = 98;
System.out.println(k<<32); // really shifts by 0
System.out.println((k<<31)<<1));
```

Prints

```
98
0
```

The same rules apply to long with `32` being replaced by `64`.